# After reading Michael Spivak's 'Calculus Fourth Edition,' which complex analysis book would you recommend?

Tags: complex-analysis, soft-question, book-recommendation

[image]

I am using ChatGPT to translate my Japanese sentences into English, including this one.

After reading Michael Spivak's 'Calculus Fourth Edition,' which complex analysis book would you recommend?

Towards the end of 'Calculus Fourth Edition,' Spivak provides an introductory explanation to complex analysis. After reading it, I can't help but feel disappointed that Spivak didn't write a book on complex analysis himself. Nevertheless, considering the 'Suggested Reading' in this book, I am contemplating whether to read Ahlfors' 'Complex Analysis' or E. Stein and R. Shakarchi's 'Complex Analysis.' One thing that concerns me is Spivak's comment, 'Rather Revolutionary when it was first published, it might now be considered somewhat old-fashioned, and you might prefer the second in a series of books (3 and counting) that have appeared more recently: [36] Fourier Analysis: An Introduction by E. Stein and R. Shakarchi. [37] Complex Analysis, by E. Stein and R. Shakarchi. [38] Real Analysis, by E. Stein and R. Shakarchi.' This seems to imply a subtle recommendation for Stein and Shakarchi over Ahlfors. Could you provide more specific details on what Spivak means by 'old-fashioned' regarding Ahlfors' book?

I also have a Japanese textbook on complex analysis by Kunihiko Kodaira, in addition to Ahlfors' book and the one by Stein and others. In Japan, Kunihiko Kodaira is a well-known mathematician.

Comment: Not a book recommendation: some topological notions (such as open sets, connected space, and compact space) are essential to the mathematical development of complex analysis. I am not sure if these notions are covered by a calculus text. If not, you may need to learn them first.

Comment: @user1551 thank you very much for your advice.